# JavaScript evaluate XPATH within an element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I am trying to get an element using document.evaluate() but also want to search only within a specific element. So for example:

```
const element = document.evaluate('.//p', ...); //I want this to return the Hello, World p element
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="someId">
      <p>Hello, World!<p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I could pass in the div with id someId into the evaluate to only search within that scope?

I know I could write the whole XPATH like .//div[@id="someId"]/p (Wouldnt work for my case) or do string concatenation but would like to find a cleaner way of doing it like passing the DOM element (or some object it contains) somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely the purpose of the second argument of [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate):

> `contextNode` specifies the context node for the query (see the [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)). It's common to pass document as the context node.

```js
const someId = document.getElementById('someId');

const result = document.evaluate('.//p', someId, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)

console.log(result.snapshotItem(0)); // Hello, World!
console.log(result.snapshotItem(1)); // null
```

```html
<div id="someId">
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Goodbye, World!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `document` for the `contextNode`, using the parent id within the query (like you asked). Like this:

```js
const snapshotType = XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE;
const result1 = document.evaluate('.//div[@id="someId"]//p', document, null, snapshotType);

console.log(`result1 contains ${result1.snapshotLength} element, namely`, result1.snapshotItem(0))

//alternatively search for the actual text
const result2 = document.evaluate('.//p[contains(text(), "Hello")]', document, null, snapshotType);

console.log(`result2 contains ${result2.snapshotLength} element, namely`, result2.snapshotItem(0));

// finally, if the element order is fixed, you can take the first one
const result3 = document.evaluate('(.//p)[1]', document, null, snapshotType);
console.log(`result3 contains ${result3.snapshotLength} element, namely`, result3.snapshotItem(0));
```

```html
<div id="someId">
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Goodbye, World!</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>And I left</p>
</div>
```